# Can't get Content-Range request to work in IIS7 and IIS8

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm doing the same kind of request to an IIS7 and IIS8 server, but I keep getting this **416** response

```
$ curl-7.23.1-win64-ssl-sspi>curl -H Range:bytes=16- -I http://my.local.host/dotnetrocks_0813_syme_battochi.mp3

HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable  
Content-Length: 45740117  
Content-Type: audio/mpeg  
Last-Modified: Wed, 24 Oct 2012 09:14:29 GMT  
Accept-Ranges: bytes  
ETag: "97ab9ff8c7b1cd1:0"  
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0  
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  
Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2012 18:54:31 GMT  
Content-Range: bytes */0
```

The range is clearly within the file size, but I'm still not getting a **206** response.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882776/curl-default-get-request-isnt-recognized-by-php.

Synopsis: Specifying header only option `-I` results in request method HEAD. Force GET instead by specifying `-X` option.

Example:
`curl -H Range:bytes=16- -I -X GET http://my.local.host/dotnetrocks_0813_syme_battochi.mp3`